# File is empty after running Python script

Tags: python, file

I am trying to write a Python script which:

- for a line containing the string `"xkcd"`(norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb), will replace `"bu.*ls"` with `"[gikuj]..n|a.[alt]|[pivo].l|i..o|[jocy]e|sh|di|oo"`
- also in a line where characters are `'='` `'a'` `'['` it will replace it with our name `"xlogin"`

I don't know how to continue, I just wrote this but it doesn't work properly because after running the code my file is empty. Here is my code, I will be very thankful if somebody shows me some examples how to continue :)

**UPDATE :** Thanks guys, it works, now I am working with this code, but I want to ask how to use OR in re.search function when I want to find more strings in line and after that change other strings

```
`import re
 output = open("output.txt","w") 
 skuska = open("skuska.txt")
 for line in skuska:
 if re.search("xkcd", line):
    output.write(re.sub(r'"bu.*ls',r'[gikuj]..n|a.[alt]|[pivo].l|i..o|      [jocy]e|sh|di|oo', line))  
if re.search("a"|"="|"[", line) :
    output.write(re.sub(r'xkcd',r'xvasko', line))
skuska.close()
output.close()`
```

Comment: did you check to make sure that your regex works? Does it go in to your condition to write to your file?

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: it seems that your code isn't getting any "xkcd" in line.... so it can't `output.write()` anything.. you should use a `print` statement to see if it can find "xkcd"...

Comment: `re.match` only finds matches at the _beginning_ of the line.  If you want to match anywhere in the line, use `re.search`.